# Sampler Dependency in jmeter execution

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, dependencies, execution

I want to have some thread dependency in Jmeter.

Suppose that I have two HTTP requests: **A** and **B**.
And I want to achieve the behaviour that if *request **A*** executes, then only *request **B*** has to be executed.

Why I need this is in my case that I have to put *request **B*** in some controller which would be executed before *request **A*** executes. In that case I want to put some dependency between these HTTP requests.

I hope that you understand my concern.
Please help me realizing that.

Answer (score 0):

Use IF Controller with expression "${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}". It will run the sampler under it if the last sampler is passed.

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: hello... sunny . thanks for ur reply... actually what I  need is I hve one thread in one controller and one thread in another controller. like I said in my question..thnku

Comment: @biyyapu Let me know if it help.If yes then you can accept the answer,see stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: haa ...I need more accurate actually . as I told in the question I need some like that and my query was not related to thread to next thread ..I have reaquest  A in one controller and request B in another controller along with some other requests also... I need to make dependency these two only and want to make sure that when we make dependency no other request after request B will not be execute.

Comment: You can use critical section controller and put both A and B in that and rest in another simpler controller with IF the last sample Ok check. Critical section controller will make sure B will be executed after A. If this is not what you are looking then share a snapshot to help me understand your scenario.BTW, if controller can also work with other controllers.

Comment: @sunny_teo..so I was trying some other method if that would not work as u told I ll attach a screen shot ..thanks a lot for ur support..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to implement this is using [Inter-Thread Communication](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/#Inter-Thread-Communication) plugin, the usage would be following:

1. When **Request A** finishes it should put something into a FIFO queue using `fifoPut` function
2. **Request B** will live under the [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) which will be checking FIFO queue size or content using `fifoSize` or `fifoPop` functions correspondingly.

This way `Request B` will be executed only when `Request A` does its job and puts something into the FIFO queue.

See [SynchronizationExample.jmx](https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/SynchronizationExample.jmx) Test Plan for reference implementation details. You will need to install Inter-Thread Communication Plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) prior to attempting opening the file

Comment: thanku..Dmitri I will try that and let u know whether it works fine ..thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTTP Cookie manager in Jmeter